# how to make user name in a dropdown to display name once in a month

Tags: php

Below is my view file code:-
here i want if for user_id =1 i have enter details for jan month then next time when i select jan month then user_id = 1 is not visible  how it can be done what to pass in controller 
In controller its just an insert code

```
 <select id="month" name="month" class="input-text">
            <option value="<?=set_value('month',$this->input->post('month'))?>">Select Month</option>
            <option value="January">&nbsp;&January</option>
            <option value="February">&nbsp;February</option>
            <option value="March">&nbsp;March</option>
            <option value="April">&nbsp;April</option>
            <option value="May">&nbsp;May</option>
            <option value="June">&nbsp;June</option>
            <option value="July">&nbsp;July</option>
            <option value="August">&nbsp;August</option>
            <option value="September">&nbsp;September</option>
            <option value="October">&nbsp;October</option>
            <option value="November">&nbsp;November</option>
            <option value="December">&nbsp;December</option>
</select>

<select id="month" name="month_name" class="input-text" >
                <option >&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Employee</option>
            <? foreach($assign_row as $user){?>     
                <option value="<?=$user['user_id']?>">&nbsp;<?=$user['f_name']?></option>
            <? } ?>
 </select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#month').change(function(){
            var status = $('#month').val();
            //alert(status);
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?=base_url()?>admin/dashboard/user_detail',
                    data: {changeStatus: $('#month').val()},
                    dataType: 'json',

             });
        });
    });
</script>

    please help
```

Comment: Post your code for DB, also to be clear what you need is if you have entered details of a user for Jan month then next time when you select it , all users except Jan are to be shown. Is that correct?

Comment: yes all users except that user whose user_id = 1

Comment: but only in current year next year jan again visible

Comment: user_id=1 but in case if you have also entered details for user_id=2,3,4..... in jan month , they will not be displayed next time you select Jan

Comment: yes i want that if i select 1,2,3,4 then these id name also not visible for jan month

Comment: Then in your query while selecting data use NOT IN('your month value') to select and retrun the records. Ex : If you have passed 01(month) using ajax then the data returned will contain all records except Jan month

Comment: $month = $this->input->post('month');
  
  $q = 'select distinct employee.user_id ,month  from  employee where employee.month = "'.$month.'"';
  $row = $this->evaluation_model->q_single($q);
  
  $q = " select user_id, f_name from users  where  user_id NOT IN ('".$row['user_id']."') and  users.active = 1 and  users.role_id <> 1 order by f_name asc "  ; 
  $assign_row = $this->user_model->q($q);

Comment: i tried this but not work i have to pass ajax here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131112/discussion-between-rahul-and-meow).

Answer (score 2):

waht can you do here is u can take one hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="countJan" />
```

Now on your change function wheb you get jan in change event increase the counter and when count is 2 you can simply remove userid with passing extra parameter.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#month').change(function(){
                var status = $('#month').val();
                var cnt =  $('#countJan').val();
                if(status == 'jan' && cnt == 2){ var hideJan = 'yes'; }
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '<?=base_url()?>admin/dashboard/user_detail',
                        data: {changeStatus: $('#month').val()},
                        dataType: 'json',

                 });
            });
        });
```

I hope it helps !!!!

Comment: I don't want it for january for instead i want for all month as i select particular id or id's for a month then next time when i select that month the id which i already selected will not visible

Comment: well here you will get the var status = $('#month').val();  values of all months. just put condition according to that

Comment: ok <input type="hidden" id="countJan" /> where i have to keep this on month dropdown or user dropdown

Comment: alert(cnt); display blank and only one name is visible on dropdown remaing not

Comment: you need to increase counter every change event.